# Recursive Chudnovsky Algorithm in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I am a computer engineering student, and I've got a project to do which is to do a Chudnovsky algorithm to calculate Pi, but the problem I've got is to do it decimal by decimal(i mean if a got a length 3 it's going to be 3.14), I have already done the code to do it and get `3.141592653589734` but I don't have any idea how to do it bit by bit using a recursive method.The code I got so far is

```
 //This class implements an interface which only contains the method calcularPi
 public class Chudnovsky_Implements implements Chudnovsky {


public  double calcularPi(int k)//This is where I'm trying to do it bit by bit which I'm probably doing it wrong.
{       
    if(k==0)
        return Pi(k);
    else {
    double resultado= (Pi(k))+(Pi(k-1));
    return resultado;

    }

}

public double Pi(int k)//Here i calculated the number Pi with a constant k that the user give(k is supposedly to be the number of digits)
{
    double numerador=(factorial(6*k)*((545140134*k)+13591409));
    double denominador =(factorial(3*k)*Math.pow(factorial(k), 3)*Math.pow(-640320, (3*k)));
    double Pi=(numerador/denominador);
    return Pi;
}

 public double factorial(int n)// This is a class to calculate an factorial of a number
 {
    if (n==0)
       return 1;
    else
       return n*(factorial(n-1));
}
```

If anything is somewhat vague or you don't quite understand English is not my main language Sorry

[This is the integer the teacher gave to us](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdeOg.png)

Comment: Recursively just means that the function calls itself: see how your factorial function calls factorial(n-1), perhaps you can do a similar thing within calculatePi() ...

Comment: Are you sure the numerator and denominator are both correct? I checked the algorithm on wiki and I am not sure if you wrote every factor... Also, if you want, you can ask in portuguese here: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/
But I will take a look at your problem here... One more thing: do you have anyother piece of code or it's all here?

Comment: I added an image of what the teacher gave to us

Comment: @LuisOrtiz I am working on it... Wait a bit, please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With recursion:

```
package q46166389;

public class Chudnovsky {

    public static void main( String[ ] args ) {
        int k = 13;

        final String outputFormat = "%." + ( k - 1 ) + "f";

        double result = new Chudnovsky( ).calculateLoop( k );

        // Format the output to the desired number of decimals
        System.out.println( "result = " + String.format( outputFormat, result ) );
        // Or just print it:
        System.out.println( "result = " + result );

        result = 1 / new Chudnovsky( ).calculateRecursive( k );

        System.out.println( "result = " + String.format( outputFormat, result ) );
        System.out.println( "result = " + result );
    }

    public double calculateLoop( int k ) {
        double result = 0;
        for ( int i = 0; i <= k; i++ ) {
            result = result + doCalc( i );
        }
        return 1 / result;
    }

    public double calculateRecursive( int k ) {
        if ( k == 0 ) { return doCalc( k ); }

        return doCalc( k ) + calculateRecursive( k - 1 );
    }

    public double doCalc( int k ) {
        double numerator = Math.pow( -1, k ) * factorial( 6 * k ) * ( 545140134 * k + 13591409 );
        double denominator = factorial( 3 * k ) * Math.pow( factorial( k ), 3 ) * Math.pow( 640320, 3 * k + 3.0 / 2.0 );
        return 12.0 * numerator / denominator;
    }

    public double factorial( int n ) {
        if ( n == 0 ) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return n * factorial( n - 1 );
        }
    }

}
```

Output:

```
result = 3.141592653590
result = 3.1415926535897936
result = 3.141592653590
result = 3.1415926535897936
```

Please note that this answer only works until k = 17 and have precision problems!
If you need more digits or more precision, you will need to use `BigDecimal`.

Comment: The thing is that i have to, its the "complicated" part of the problem

Comment: @LuisOrtiz checked this new version, please.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use recursion for the same logic as used by you, then you shall change

```
else {
    double resultado= (Pi(k))+(Pi(k-1));
    return resultado;
}
```

to

```
else {
    double resultado= calcularPi(k)+ calcularPi(k-1); // calling the same method from within it
    return resultado;
}
```

which is what is used in your `factorial` method as well.

Comment: Yeah i did that a while ago but the thing is that i need to give the number with certain number of digits as i said and that i belive is going to keep giving me the number but with a ton of decimals

Comment: @LuisOrtiz you didn't mention what digit limits you need to set in the result. Probably place a check for number of digits in that case and `return` if the number of digits is reached or `roundOff` otherwise.